# John The Ripper and PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hash, password-cracking, john-the-ripper

I am trying to hash a list of passwords with PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 and then crack them using John. However, John does not recognise the hashes and I get a No Hashes Found error. It works with SHA256, but I need PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1. I have looked everywhere and have exhausted all my options. What is the correct format of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 that is recognised by John and will let me crack it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely supported, and definitely one of these format names (one for CPU, and the other for GPU):

```
$ john --list=formats | tr ',' '\n' | grep PBKDF2 | grep SHA1
 PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1
PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1-opencl
```

At this point, it sounds more likely that your method of *generating* PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 is the issue here. Have you tried your attack against a "known good" hash? One that's easy to grab and almost certain to work is the example that ships with John itself:

```
$ john --list=format-details --format=PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1
PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1    125 16  128 01020003    22  PBKDF2-SHA1 128/128 AVX 4x  0x107   20  192 iteration count 0   $pbkdf2-hmac-sha1$1000.fd11cde0.27de197171e6d49fc5f55c9ef06c0d8751cd7250
```

... which should be crackable by dropping it into a file and running john against it:

```
$ cat test.hash
$pbkdf2-hmac-sha1$1000.fd11cde0.27de197171e6d49fc5f55c9ef06c0d8751cd7250

$ cat wordlist.txt 
3956

$ john --format=PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 --wordlist=wordlist.txt test.hash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 royce royce 24690360 Jun 16 14:50 /usr/local/src/sec/crack/john-latest/run/john
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 [PBKDF2-SHA1 128/128 AVX 4x])
Cost 1 (iteration count) is 1000 for all loaded hashes
Will run 4 OpenMP threads
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
Warning: Only 1 candidate left, minimum 16 needed for performance.
3956             (?)
1g 0:00:00:00 DONE (2020-07-25 05:40) 4.347g/s 4.347p/s 4.347c/s 4.347C/s 3956
Use the "--show --format=PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1" options to display all of the cracked passwords reliably
Session completed.
```

One common error is that, if you're trying to crack the hash on the command line directly and not attacking hashes within a file, depending on your operating system and shell, the '$' has special meaning to the shell (variable substitution) and results in the hash being mangled. Putting the hashes in a file, or putting appropriate quotes around the hash, or escaping the dollar signs (usually with a backslash), will address this issue.

If that's not it, then it's most likely that there's something wrong with how your hashes are being generated.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, this is so helpful and has relieved me from quite alot of stress. I will make some changes using the information you have supplied. Again, thank you for your response!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help! And if this answer was a good answer to your question, please mark it as the accepted answer - both for future people with the same question, and also because then I get a couple points. ;)

Comment: I did indeed get the John example hash to crack, so thanks for that! I have been hunting high and low for a method of hashing a wordlist to the same format as the John example, but with 0 luck. Is there any way that you know of that I can do this? I tried using passlib.hash in Python however I just get the hash, not in the same format as John. What exactly is the format? Is it just the hash of the salt and the hash of the password concatenated?

Comment: Sounds like you need to drop back to some fundamentals. Salt and hash are concatenated prior to hashing for most hashes. Recommendation: see if you can find some other high-profile FOSS platform that is already doing what you're looking to do, and study its source.